# Backbone.js inserting arbitrary number of rows views into a table

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

- I have a table that shows a collection of backbone objects.
- I want to be able to click on an object's table row and then show its children in a series of table rows below.
- The children will be in a collection that I get from a call to the RESTful endpoint
- For each of the objects in that collection, I intend to create a row - view object
- I then want to pass the row id of the parent object to a jquery selector and insert the views after the parent object's row

Is this possible? I am used to binding a view to a specific DOM element and not arbitrarily inserting it with JQuery selector.  How would I do that?

Here is my attempt:

(the parent backbone view that creates and calls render on the child row view (object that has id of 23 should be rendered below 22)

```
unfold: (e) ->
   @single_seg = @segments.get("23")
   row = new RP.Views.AudienceRow(
      el: this.$("#22").after(row),
      dmp_segment: @single_seg
    ) 
   console.log "row view created"
   row.render()
```

Here is the code in the row view:

```
    RP.Views.AudienceRow = Backbone.View.extend
       template: JST["dmp/AudienceRow"]

    initialize: ->
      @segment = @options.segment

    render: ->
      console.log "render function working"
      this.$el.html( @template() )
      this
```

Right now, it doesn't quite work because it replaces the existing parent row.  I think this is because my Jquery selector isn't specified correctly? 
(doing the below in coffeescript, sorry if that throws people off)

Comment: I've also tried using insertAfter instead of "after" and when I do that, nothing happens - the parent row is not overwritten, but nor do I see the child row anywhere.

Comment: Not that this comment will help you with your current problem, but a very popular and stable Backbone framework called Backbone.Marionette, makes your problem trivially easy to do in a very extensible way. Http://marionettejs.org

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer- this isn't a pretty way to do it, but it works. I had to create a hidden table, initially, bind the new view to the hidden table and then use the JQuery selector after to move it to the right position:

```
    unfold: (e) ->
      @single_seg = @segments.get("24")
      row = new RP.Views.AudienceRow(
      el: this.$("#test"),
      dmp_segment: @single_seg) 
      console.log "row view created"
      row.render()
      this.$("#test").insertAfter("#5490690d4d6963d7420c0000")

<table id="hide-me">
    <tbody id="test">
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: There's technically nothing wrong with this if you're not using a templating engine. Your take is a primitive template. Of course i does you take advantage of Backbone's underscore templates to clean up your code